# Rails & Bootstrap - Toggle navbar button unresponsive

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

Can't seem to get this fixed, hopefully someone can help me. The nav-bar collapses fine, but the toggle button is unresponsive.

Using the Twitter Boostrap gem and have followed all the instructions.

Gemfile:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Application CSS:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require_tree .
```

Application JS:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Layout:

```
!!!
%html
 %head
%title=yield(:title)
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", controller.controller_name
= javascript_include_tag "application", controller.controller_name
= csrf_meta_tags
%meta{ :name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}

%body
.navbar.navbar-fluid-top.navbar-fixed-top
    .container
        %button{ :class => "btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => ".navbar-collapse" }
            %span{ :class=> "sr-only" } Toggle Navigation
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
    .container.nav-collapse
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            -if User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
                %li
                    =link_to 'Home', '/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'About', '/about/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Work', '/portfolios/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Journal', '/journals/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Get in Touch', '/contact/'
                %li
                    |
                %li
                    =link_to 'Users', '/users'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete

            -else
                %li
                    =link_to 'Home', '/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'About', '/about/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Work', '/portfolios/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Journal', '/journals/'
                %li
                    =link_to 'Get in Touch', '/contact'

= yield

=render 'layouts/footer'
```

Comment: Have you checked in the browser that it's definitely getting Bootstrap's Javascript file? Does any other bootstrap related javascript stuff work?

Comment: I just checked and nothings coming up. What does that mean I'm missing? @joshua.paling

Comment: what does your application.js file look like? Paste it above. You should have a line like this: //= require bootstrap

Comment: Woops sorry, I noticed you've already got that (or the equivalent for your gem). I'm not sure what could be wrong. It's working for me - I'm using the sass version of bootstrap: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as the OP, only my application.js file did NOT include

`//= require bootstrap`

Also I note the OP has

`//= require twitter/bootstrap`

Which is not the same, strictly speaking.

Anyway- I don't know why the require clause was not automatically added in my case, nor why it was not obvious in any of the documentation I located that it needs to be present or manually added... Thanks to Joshua Paling for the correct answer in my case.

`Application.js:`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```